# parsing comma seperated values in MS-SQL (no csv or such)

Tags: sql-server, string, join

I use a closed source commercial application that uses an MS-SQL database. I regularly have to query this database myself for various purposes. This means the table and database design is fixed, and I can't do anything about it at all. I just have to live with it. Now I have two tables with the following layouts (abstracted, not to discredit the software/database designer)

```
t1: ID (int), att1(varchar), att2(varchar), .... attx(varchar)

t2: ID (int), t1_ids(varchar)
```

Now the contents of this `t1_ids` is (shudder) a comma separated list of t1 id's. (for example 12, 456, 43, 675, 54). What I want to do is (you guessed it) join those two tables.

Fortunately for me, these are very small tables, and I don't care about performance in terms of complexity at all (could be `O(n^m)` as far as I care).

Ideally I would like to make a view that joins these two tables. I don't have any requirements for inserting or updating, just for select statements. What would be the easiest and clearest (in terms of maintainability) way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first and last too use this:

```
select * 
from t1 
    join t2 on '%,' + t1.ID + ',%' like ',' + T2.t1_ids + ','
```

It doesn't matter if T2.t1_ids start or end with . The valid values are enclosed by commas.

Comment: Same comment as Jani, this doesn't work for the first and the last item, as they don't have commas on both sides

Comment: @Martijn Gotcha. Fixed my code. I really worked with that pattern in the past.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I realised after posting this answer the `PARSENAME` function can only return one part of the parsed string, so it's not a useful as I thought it would be in your situation.

Searching SO for alternative solutions I came across an interesting answer to this question: [Split String in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/2685#2685)

If you can add triggers to your database then you could call the split string on `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` to maintain another table with the id's separated as rows. Then you can create your view using that table.

I know you said you don't mind about the speed of the query but at least that way you are not parsing all the strings every time you query the data.